# Platform with movement in godot 4.2

Tags: godot, godot4

I am 17 years old and I want to learn how to create video games (it should be noted that I am studying software engineering and I already have some logic), the reason for my question, as you can see in the title, is that I want to create a platform that moves and that my characteryBody or my player can move around in it, I have been watching videos but the videos that exist make the platform in godot3, I clarify that all this text is translated and the truth is I don't know if I understood

As I said right now I have not tried anything since all the information you are looking for is there but for godot 3, I have watched videos on YouTube, and searched for information on some internet pages but none of them have helped me.
If you have any advice to give me, you can tell me (I've already started studying English)

Comment: can you show us what you've tried and how your character is structured etc? I'd recommend trying first and then asking the exact pin point problem on stackoverflow :)